# How to animate a wide image (right to left) as the background of my activity?

Tags: android, android-animation

I need to set my wide image (1800x1201px) as the background of my activity so I can place the app logo and sign in/sign up buttons above.

I tried using a `FrameLayout` with an `ImageView`. The animation is working, however the image is not filling the entire `FrameLayout` height.

Activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/splash_base_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="br.com.myapp.app.activities.SplashActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/splash_bg_image"
        android:src="@drawable/splash_background"
        android:contentDescription=""
        android:scaleType="matrix"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:cropToPadding="false" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Activity Class

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        animateBackground();
    }

    private void animateBackground() {
        final ImageView splashImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.splash_bg_image);

        splashImage.startAnimation(outToLeftAnimation());
    }

    private Animation outToLeftAnimation() {
        Animation outtoLeft = new TranslateAnimation(
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, -1.0f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);
        outtoLeft.setDuration(20000L);
        return outtoLeft;
    }
}
```

Here's how it is currently previewed on Android Studio:
[image: Android Studio preview]

I tried setting `layout_height` both with `match_parent` and `wrap_content`, but could not find the right `scaleType` to make it fill the screen height and create the right to left animation.

### UPDATE

I created a larger image (3840x2560) for xxx-hdpi devices and now the preview shows the image the way I need, however when I run the app it has blank spaces on top and bottom.

Also I need to create kind of a "boomerang" animation so when the image has gone right to left it reverses the animation from left to right, and so on.

Updated image:
[image: Updated image]

Answer (score 0):

Change `android:adjustViewBounds="false"` to `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` and make its height `match_parent` and it's done.

Answer (score 0):

Hi can you refer this example [Android: proportionally stretch an ImageView to fit the whole screen width while maintaining its aspect ratio](http://www.ryadel.com/en/android-proportionally-stretch-imageview-fit-whole-screen-width-maintaining-aspect-ratio/)

Comment: Didn't work either: http://imgur.com/a/UQfEh. I tried both with FrameLayout and RelativeLayout containers.